# Как написать функцию смены директории на Python?

Tags: python

Изучаю Python, и в рамках изучения пишу консольный файловый менеджер. Написал основные функции вроде создания и удаления папок, но не могу понять, как написать функцию смены директории. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `os.chdir(path)` - смена текущей директории.

Comment: Что вы в данном случае понимаете под сменой директории? Если речь идёт о текущей директории, то это внутренняя логика вашего файлового менеджера. Никакой специальной функции не нужно, просто у вас есть какая-то переменная с путём до текущей директории, и вы её меняете в зависимости от действий пользователя.